# Bukkit API why won't it recognize these blocks

Tags: java, bukkit

I am using Spigot API 1.8.6, I put bukkit in the title because they are literally almost exactly the same.

I have a configuration selection that gets item ids from the config along with their value. The item ids are turned into materials. However 173, and 42, which are iron block and coal block are being skipped. This is what I have:

```
for(String key : plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("sellall"+ranks).getKeys(false))
{
    int id = Integer.valueOf(key);
    Material material = Material.getMaterial(id);
}
```

I then check the player's inventory for the material, the materials is found for every single item id *BESIDES* 42 and 173, iron block and coal block. My question is why do they skip them and how can I fix it.

Here is what I have tried, since they are being skipped I tried this:

```
String f = key;
Material mat = Material.getMaterial(f.toUpperCase());
if(mat == Material.IRON_BLOCK||mat == Material.COAL_BLOCK)
{
    // continue with code like the else
}
else
{
    // same code as if they are iron block or coal block
}
```

However this does the same and skips them.

NOTE: I have tried multiple versions of spigot

Final Question: Why is Bukkit/Spigot API skipping iron block and coal block, but not skipping everything else, How would I fix it?

Comment: I tried scanning a player's inventory for coal and iron blocks (always detected/found them) and `Material.getMaterial(41)` as well `Material.getMaterial(173)` returned the correct Materials. I used Craftbukkit as well as Spigot versions 1.8.3 and 1.8.7. Could something else in your code be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is all about item IDs.

Look at the Javadoc for [`Material.getMaterial(int)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Material.html#getMaterial(int)):

> Deprecated. Magic value

[This post](https://bukkit.org/threads/whats-a-magic-value.172825/#post-1838708) explains what magic values are:

> Magic values are values that do not clearly demonstrate what they represent, eg, an item ID. They have deprecated these as minecraft changes could easily break the ID system, and they wish for people to use the bukkit API Enum equivalents that currently exist. For example, using the Material type instead of block ids.

Then you should use [`Material.getMaterial(String)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Material.html#getMaterial(java.lang.String)) instead.

Your first try didn't work because `key` was a number.
You have to save the enum constant instead (with [`Enum.name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name())).

```
FileConfiguration config; // ...
ConfigurationSection path = config.getConfigurationSection("sellall" + ranks);

Material key = Material.IRON_BLOCK;
Object value; // ...
path.set(key.name(), value);

for (String key : path.getKeys(false)) {
    Material material = Material.getMaterial(key);
}
```